# HTTP Get request with restSharp using Parameters

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I did this request in postman and it works fine

[image]

But when I try to do the same request using RestSharp I´m having this response:

[image]

my csharp code:

```
        public string FindWeatherStation(string query)
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient(new Uri($"https://api.meteostat.net/v2/stations/search"));
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

            request.AddHeader("x-api-key", "mykey");
            request.AddParameter("query", query);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var result = response.Content;

            return result;

        }
```

the query value is vancouver as well

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Creating the RestClient object by simply pass the url as string:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.meteostat.net/v2/stations/search");
```

Then using *ParameterType.RequestBody* as the third parameter to the *AddParameter* method:

```
request.AddParameter("query", query, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```